Could not find add method: AddExcludedTemplate (type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration)
I'm using Sitecore 10.4 and I'm planning to exclude the template and created the separated file with the name of "SpecificationLookupIndexConfiguration.config" and below is the content
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <contentSearch>
            <indexConfigurations>
                <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
                    <documentOptions ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/documentOptions">
                        <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedTemplate">
                            <SpecificationLookupTemplateIdExtended>{BA824B26-C042-4DE9-9478-FEB2EE3958BD}</SpecificationLookupTemplateIdExtended>
                        </exclude>
                    </documentOptions>
                </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
            </indexConfigurations>
        </contentSearch>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>

and deployed i'm getting the below error.
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not find add method: AddExcludedTemplate (type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Sitecore.Exceptions.RequiredObjectIsNullException: Could not find add method: AddExcludedTemplate (type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[RequiredObjectIsNullException: Could not find add method: AddExcludedTemplate (type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration)]
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(Object obj, Object[] properties) +1929
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +641
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +170
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +116
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +545
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +842
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +545
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration() +309
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +732
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +189
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultSearchIndexes.get_CsConfig() +16
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultSearchIndexes.GeAllIndexes() +11
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrNetIntegration.DefaultSolrStartUp..ctor(BaseSearchIndexes indexes) +59
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeSolrProvider.Process(PipelineArgs args) +72
   (Object , Object ) +9
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1450
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +146
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +918
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +584
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not find add method: AddExcludedTemplate (type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +719
enter code here



You can patch your custom index configuration as below to exclude template from indexing.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
       <indexConfigurations>
          <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
             <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                 <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedTemplate">
                     <SpecificationLookupTemplateIdExtended>{BA824B26-C042-4DE9-9478-FEB2EE3958BD}</SpecificationLookupTemplateIdExtended>
                 </exclude>
              </documentOptions>
          </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
       </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

Instead of using AddExcludedTemplate, you might need to configure template exclusions in a different way. In Sitecore 10.4, exclusions for templates can be done directly in the Solr configuration. A common method is to use the ExcludedTemplates field or adjust the index configuration in other ways.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <contentSearch>
            <indexConfigurations>
               <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                     <documentOptions ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/documentOptions">
                        <excludeTemplates hint="list:AddExcludedTemplate">
                            <template>{BA824B26-C042-4DE9-9478-FEB2EE3958BD}</template>
                        </excludeTemplates>
                    </documentOptions>
                </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
            </indexConfigurations>
        </contentSearch>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>

This configuration uses the correct XML patching syntax to exclude a specific template from being indexed. The excludeTemplates tag is used instead of exclude, and the hint list:AddExcludedTemplate should properly call the method to add this template to the exclusion list.
Hope this help!!
